# Using a custom icon font with asciidoctor-pdf

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I have managed to use a custom icon font replacing FontAwesome in AsciiDoc by doing the following.

I have placed my font files in my AsciiDoc root directory:

- icons.css
- fonts/icons.eot
- fonts/icons.svg
- fonts/icons.ttf
- fonts/icons.woff

I have set the following properties in the AsciiDoc document:

```
:icons: font
:iconfont-remote!:
:iconfont-name: icons
```

The icon is rendered correctly in the HTML output and in the VS code plugin preview. When creating a pdf from the asciidoc, though, the icon doesn't appear. I use this command to generate the pdf:

```
bundle exec asciidoctor-pdf book.adoc -o out/book.pdf
```

And I receive this error (the icon is not renderered):

```
asciidoctor: WARNING: my-icon is not a valid icon name in the fa icon set
```

Does asciidoctor-pdf need to be pointed to the custom icon font in some way? I have tried looking for answers in the docs but couldn't find any (as a matter of fact, also making this work with HTML took some experimentation).

Answer (score 0):

asciidoctor-pdf does not have the same flexibility as asciidoctor for icon fonts, see https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/icons/#font

> Icon-based fonts are handled by the prawn-icon gem.

If you want to use one of the available set you will need to set the `:icons:` and `:icon-set:` document attributes, at best from the command line so you do not have a conflict with HTML conversion.

```
asciidoctor-pdf -a icons=font -a icon-set=fas sample.adoc
```

The fonts available are:

- fa - Font Awesome 4 (default, deprecated)
- fas - Font Awesome - Solid
- fab - Font Awesome - Brands
- far - Font Awesome - Regular
- fi - Foundation Icons
- pf - Payment font (deprecated)